# If ${ X_n }$ is a sequence of real numbers and E = set of all numbers z s.t. $\exists$ a subsequence ${ X_{n_k} }$ convergent to z, then E is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

I have to show that, if ${ X_n }$ is a sequence of real numbers and $E$ denotes the set of all numbers $z$ that have the property that there exists a subsequence ${ X_{n_k} }$ convergent to $z$, then $E$ is closed.

So I have to show that any accumulation point of $E$, say $x$, is in the set $E$. By the definition of accumulation points of $E$ we have that  for every $c>0$ the intersection
$$(x-c,x+c) \cap E$$

contains infinitely many points. So there exists a subsequence ${ X_{n_k} }$ convergent to some $z$ arbitrary close to $x$.  If ${ X_{n_k} }$ converges to $z$ then for all $\epsilon >0 $ there is an integer $N$ so that 
$$ \lvert { X_{n_k} } - z \rvert < \epsilon$$

whenever $n\geq N$. Choose $z$ such that $z>x>0$, then it follows that $$ \lvert { X_{n_k} } - x \rvert < \lvert { X_{n_k} } - z \rvert < \epsilon$$
whenever $n\geq N$. Thus $x$ converges to $x_{n_k}$ as well, so $x\in E$.

QED

Does my idea make sense? Is it rigorous? Any pointers/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not true that from $z>x>0$ it follows that $|X_{n_k}-x|<|X_{n_k}-z|$.

Comment: oh duh, it is only true if $X_{n_k}$ is negative whenever n $\geq N$

Comment: Hint: given a point $x$ in the closure of $E$ you are looking for some $X_n$ which is very close to it. To do this you can first find a $z$ in $E$ which is very very close to $x$ and then find a $X_n$ which is very very close to $z$. Then $X_n$ will be very close to $x$. Make this rigorous!